# gmap api v3 autocomplete not working in an "integrated IE7/8"

Tags: google-maps-api-3

My IE8 is integrated in the VC++ application, the web application must run in this "integrated IE Browser". The autocomplete function works in a standalone IE8 and FF15 but not in that "integrated IE8". If I input something in the text field, not only the autocomplete don't work, the input text will also be cleared automatically when focus out.

if I set the value forcely like following, gmap autocomplete will work (only) for that input.

```
<input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50" value="london" />
```

So I thought at the beginning that the value just can not be input, however the other autocomplete fields using jQuery autocomplete work just fine. I wonder what could cause this kind of problem?

Comment: Is  the integrated IE Browser connected to internet??

Comment: yes, I also have tried to call the maps.google.com directly in the integrated IE Browser, and their autocomplete works.

Comment: I solve the problem, the IE can be configured in the VC++ Application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem, the IE can be configured in the VC++ Application